# This branch is 1 commit ahead of

Tags: git, github

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I am trying to sync my fork with upstream as it was several commits behind. I followed guide here:

https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/

After I do steps described above and push them a new commit appears:

Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/master'

Now my fork is one commit ahead of upstream. Why is that and what can I do?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Configure an upstream for your fork: This upstream is the original repository from which you have forked.

A. Open Git Bash.

B. List the current configured remote repository for your fork.

```
$ git remote -v
> origin  https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (fetch)
> origin  https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (push)
```

B. Specify a new remote upstream repository that will be synced with the fork.

```
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git
```

C. Verify the new upstream repository you've specified for your fork.

```
$ git remote -v
> origin    https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (fetch)
> origin    https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (push)
> upstream  https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
> upstream  https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

> 2. Sync a fork of a repository to keep it up-to-date with the upstream repository.

A. Change the current working directory to your local project.

B. Fetch the branches and their respective commits from the upstream repository. Commits to master will be stored in a local branch, upstream/master.

```
$ git fetch upstream
> remote: Counting objects: 75, done.
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (53/53), done.
> remote: Total 62 (delta 27), reused 44 (delta 9)
> Unpacking objects: 100% (62/62), done.
> From https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY
>  * [new branch]      master     -> upstream/master
```

C. Check out your fork's local master branch.

```
$ git checkout master
> Switched to branch 'master'
```

D. Merge the changes from upstream/master into your local master branch. This brings your fork's master branch into sync with the upstream repository, without losing your local changes.

```
$ git merge upstream/master
> Updating a422352..5fdff0f
> Fast-forward
>  README                    |    9 -------
>  README.md                 |    7 ++++++
>  2 files changed, 7 insertions(+), 9 deletions(-)
>  delete mode 100644 README
>  create mode 100644 README.md
```

If your local branch didn't have any unique commits, Git will instead perform a "fast-forward":

```
$ git merge upstream/master
> Updating 34e91da..16c56ad
> Fast-forward
>  README.md                 |    5 +++--
>  1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

3. This upadtes your local repositories (sync local repositories with upstream). To push changes to Github (do the same to your repositories on Github), push:

   $ git push

Source: [Syncing A Fork On Github](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/syncing-a-fork)

Answer (score 1):

You have merged changes to upstream/master into your project, and then committed the merge to your branch. Since this involves making a commit that came after all the commits on upstream/master, the *merge itself* is causing your branch to be one commit ahead.

If you want to synchronize upstream/master with your current branch (i.e. add the merged material to it) then you must run `git push upstream master` (if you are allowed) or get the repo's owner to pull your changes.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. If I run "git push upstream master" command I get permission denied message and my fork is still one commit ahead.

Comment: @trree Ah, so upstream/master isn't your repo. Unfortunately there's nothing you can do in that case unless you can get the repo's owner to pull your changes. Altered my answer to fit.

Answer (score 1):

well that makes sense. you pushed to your own fork. But the original repo, has not yet pulled your new commits, so your fork is ahead of the upstream/original repo. To contribute to the original repo you probably want to make a pull request.